# Xamarin Forms - Units in px, dp, percentage or? What is the unit type used by xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, pixel, units-of-measurement

If i set the width of a label to 50 or size of label to 12, what does that mean in Xamarin Forms? Does it scale on different devices? So will my tekst be bigger on a tablet with size 12 then tekst on a phone with size 12? What about widthrequest and heightrequest?

Hope someone can clear this up.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05

Comment: The sizes are device-independent units recognized independently by each platform

Answer (score 1):

It will be consistent on every device, or theoretically should be consistent on every device. Here is more info about [font size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#font-size). The height request should be consistent on both Android and iOS for the height of a label, although I am not sure what unit it is in. I am gonna assume pixels, but could be wrong.

You can use [Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device) if you want different sizes on different device types.

Comment: default is DP density independent pixel. If it was pixel text would not be display density proportional

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Xamarin documentation:

> These sizes are not pixels. Instead, they are **device-independent units** recognized independently by each platform.

Check the complete documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05).